# is it impossible to retrieve record in webpage using DFP API using PHP

Tags: php, api, google-dfp, adsense-api

I'm new to the DFP and have a quick question. 
I've read inside the examples code that it is meant to be run from a command line (not as a webpage). Could you please tell me, does it mean that using php it's impossible to retrieve data and display on my private website?

Comment: it's not impossible, it just means you need to execute commands on your server, which you can do by using `exec()` or `shell_exec()`, however DO NOT use these with ANY kind of user input as that is a MASSIVE security hole.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I want to manage an admin panel where i want to view/add/edit/delete the company/orders/LineItems etc from admin panel

Comment: however, I have execute these scripts in local server then it displays record in webpage properly. Now i am confused. Is it ok to use these scripts for client ? or it will create problem in future.